# Why is this For loop only iterating one time in Google App Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**Objective:** In Google App Script, on a Sheet, I want this script to look at the entire row, cell by cell, and compare cell color with the cell two rows below the active cell. If they match, it sets the value of the cell to X.

```
function printDCLoop(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var targetCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var refCell = targetCell.offset(2,0);

  var targetBkg = targetCell.getBackground();
  var refBkg = refCell.getBackground();

  for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(refBkg == targetBkg){
      targetCell.setValue("X");
      targetCell.offset(0,1).activate();
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:** I can make the script work as intended on individual cells. I cannot figure out how to make it loop over the entire row. In particular, I don't think I'm using this right:
`for(var i=0;i<4;i++){`

I know this would only iterate four times, but right now what's happening is that it is iterating 1 time and not again. I don't know if this particular use case would be more suited to forEach, or if I should be using a different method of accomplishing this goal at all. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How are you checking that it runs only one time? `targetCell` never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try:

```
function printDCLoop() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var targetRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var numberOfColumns = 5;  //Manually define this on how many columns you have
  var refRow = targetRow + 2

  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
    var targetBkg = sheet.getRange(targetRow,i).getBackground();
    var refBkg = sheet.getRange(refRow,i).getBackground();
    if (refBkg == targetBkg) {
      sheet.getRange(targetRow,i).setValue("X");
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result:

###### From:

[image]

###### To:

[image]

##### Explanation:

The reason you are not iterating to the whole row is because you are using getCurrentCell, which in your situation it never changes and you are setting value X to it. You should use `getRow()` for the ***targetRow*** instead then iterate through its columns. Then just add 2 to get the ***refRow***. Then to get the exact cell address use `getRange()` with the **targetRow** and the iteration of the column.

On the script I shared you need to manually change the numberOfColumns to how many columns you will iterate over.

##### References:

- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: Thank you so much @Logan. This was exactly what was needed! I'm getting more familiar with GAS, but this is my first time working with loops. I guess I thought if I modified the loop to move the active cell over at the end, it would continue to trigger it. I appreciate you!

Comment: I have another question for you. If I wanted to iterate this loop over each odd-numbered row in my sheet, what would I add? I've spent the better part of today with wrapping your previous example in a for loop that counts the rows, and then when that didn't work, I tried forEach loops with no success either. Thank you in advance!

Comment: HI @Bysshe sorry I just got back to it now. Is your concern resolved?

Comment: I mean, you helped me plenty with the initial question! I just can't wrap my head around how to have the script execute on the active row, then move up to the next next row. I want to figure it out though!